# How to run espresso instrumentation test precondition on PC JVM?

Tags: junit, integration-testing, android-espresso, android-instrumentation, preconditions

I'm using espresso lib for android instrumentation tests. I also need to run precondition before tests (create account on web server, maybe some other data in future.)

I realized, that instrumentation test code actually runs on phone's JVM. I cannot run preconditions from phone, because of I'm planning to use jar-bundled test custom test framework where that precondition already implemented.

I there a way to run preconditions on PC JVM in android instrumentation test?

Comment: You could create an api endpoint which runs the preconditions and call it from the instrumentation test.